# MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation AddFluentValidationRules using the Command Handler pattern

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-2.1, fluentvalidation, swashbuckle

Trying to get MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation to work using the Command Handler pattern from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/microservice-application-layer-implementation-web-api

Using ASP .Net Core 2.2
MicroElements.Swashbuckle.FluentValidation v3.0.0-alpha.1 (as an assembly not a package ref)
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.0.0-rc2

I have this is Startup.cs

```
return services.AddSwaggerGen(setup =>
            {
                setup.AddFluentValidationRules();                
            });
```

using fluent Validation

This does not extract the Fluent validations into schema for the request body object.

```
    public class AddModelsCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<AddModelsCommand>
    {
        public AddModelsCommandValidator()
        {
            //1. validate request
            RuleFor(e => e.Model).InvalidRequestValidation();

            When(x => x.Model != null, () =>
            {
                //2. validate request body
                RuleFor(e => e.Model.ModelCode).StringRequiredValidation();
                RuleFor(e => e.Model.ModelCode).StringMaxLengthValidation(5);
                RuleFor(e => e.Model.ProgramName).StringRequiredValidation();
                RuleFor(e => e.Model.ProgramName).StringMaxLengthValidation(50);
            });
        }
    }

    public class AddModelsCommand : IRequest<AddModelsCommandResult>
    {
        public Model Model { get; }

        public AddModelsCommand(Model model)
        {
            Model = model;
        }
    }

    public class Model
    {   
        /// <summary>
        /// Unique code of the Model
        /// </summary>
        public string ModelCode { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The name of the Program
        /// </summary>
        public string ProgramName { get; set; }
    }
```

The following code *does* extract the Fluent validations into schema for the request body object. (because 1. the AbstractValidator is on the Model not the Command, and 2. I have removed the conditional When() validation)

```
public class AddModelsCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<Model>
    {
        public AddModelsCommandValidator()
        {

                //2. validate request body
                RuleFor(e => e.ModelCode).StringRequiredValidation();
                RuleFor(e => e.ModelCode).StringMaxLengthValidation(5);
                RuleFor(e => e.ProgramName).StringRequiredValidation();
                RuleFor(e => e.ProgramName).StringMaxLengthValidation(50);
        }
    }
```

Is there way to call AddFluentValidationRules and also use the Command Handler pattern?

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is `AbstractValidator<Model>` *has* to be used..
`AbstractValidator<Command`> does not really make sense